# Need help in executing MySQL queries through VS2008 using ODBC

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, odbc

I'm developing a small project (just for learning, I'm not a pro) which involves creating software which could be used by a store owner for invoice generation.  It involves storing all the store's products in a MySQL 5.5 database.  Visual Studio 2008 is used for front end (Project was started in VS2005, later converted).  MySQL ODBC Driver 5.1 is used for connection purposes.  I'm still a student and haven't been able to learn .NET yet.  So, I used the [following link](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql/myodbc-connector) to connect the Database and the interface.  I'm able to obtain all the data from the database like 'Product Name', 'Price' etc on the VB's forms through labels.

Now, for the purpose of invoice generation, the data in the labels i.e, 'Product Name' and 'Price' should be added to another table named 'Cart' whenever a button named 'Add to Cart' is pressed.  How can I implement it?  I mean, could anyone provide me with a code snippet that fetches the data being displayed in the labels and adds it to another table through 'INSERT' statement?  Thanks in advance.

P.S Basically what I need is a code snippet in VB that lets me execute an SQL query(any one like INSERT or SELECT or UPDATE) when a button is pressed in a form.

Answer (score 0):

*Products*

```
|id|  name  | price |
| 1|  Acer  |  10   |
| 2|  Dell  |  100  |
| 3| Lenovo |  100  |
```

**id** - unique id of the row -> therefore the product

*Orders*

```
| id|  user_id  |    date    | finished | delivery_address | billing_address |
|  1|    107    | 10.02.2012 |     1    |                  |                 |
|  2|    309    | 17.04.2012 |     0    |                  |                 |
```

**id** - unique id of the order
**user_id** - id of the user who placed the order
**finished** - Whether it should continue to appear in the shopping cart

*Cart*

```
| id| order_id | product | quantity |
|  1|     1    |    2    |    10    |
|  2|     1    |    3    |    20    |
```

**id** - just a unique id you can use it for something someday
**order_id** - The id of the order

You asked for a query:

```
INSERT INTO `cart` (order_id, product, quantity) VALUES (2, 1, 300);
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I wasn't clear enough in the question. Sorry for my bad english. What I'm exactly looking for is a VB.net code that executes the "INSERT into cart(cartid, pid) values(1, 701)" query when a button in the Visual Studio's form is pressed. That is, the code that should be added after "Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click " that executes the above insert query.